Prove that $\mathbb{P} = \{A\in\mathbb{D} \mid A \cap D \in \mathbb{D}\}$ is a $d$-system
I'm trying to prove this lemma from Erhan Cinlar's Probability and Stochastics book (page 3).
Let $\mathbb{D}$ be a $d$-system on $E$. Fix $D\in \mathbb{D}$, and define $\mathbb{P} = \{A \in \mathbb{D}\mid A\cap D \in \mathbb{D}\}$. Prove that $\mathbb{P}$ is again a $d$-system on $E$.
First, $E = E \cap D \in \mathbb{D}$, because $\mathbb{D}$ is a $d$-system. So, $E\in\mathbb{P}$.
Second, let $A, B \in \mathbb{P}$ such that $A\subset B$. We want to show that $B\setminus A \in \mathbb{P}$. Consider $(B\setminus A) \cap D = (B \cap D)\setminus (A \cap D)$. Now, $A, B \in \mathbb{P} \rightarrow A\cap D, B \cap D \in \mathbb{D}$. Additionally, $A\cap D \subset B\cap D$. So, $(B\cap D)\setminus (A\cap D) \in \mathbb{D}$. Therefore, $B\setminus A \in \mathbb{P}$.
Third, let $(A_n)$ be an increasing sequence in $\mathbb{P}$ with limit $A$. We want to show that $A \in \mathbb{P}$. Since $A_n \in \mathbb{P} \rightarrow A_n \cap D \in \mathbb{D}$. Hence, $(A_n \cap D)$ is an increasing sequence in $\mathbb{D}$ with limit $A\cap D$. Since $\mathbb{D}$ is a $d$-system, $A\cap D \in \mathbb{D}$. Therefore, $A \in \mathbb{P}$.
Does this proof look okay?
